# v-for duplicating th of tr same code is working fine for other objects

Tags: vue.js, laravel-nova

I have seen few solutions online but It did not solve my problem. I am getting JSON object in the response.

```
        <!-- Show Negativita Check Azienda -->
        <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-fixed w-full mt-4" v-if="showTableAzienda" v-for="item in impreses">
            <thead class="bg-gray-900">
            <tr>
                <th>Codice Fiscale</th>
                <th>Flag Domande</th>
                <th>Flag Pregiudizievoli</th>
                <th>Flag Procedure</th>
                <th>Flag Protesti</th>
                <th>Data Evasione</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-center py-6" >
            <tr>
                <td>{{item.codice_fiscale}}</td>
                <td>{{item.flagDomande}}</td>
                <td>{{item.flagPregiudizievoli}}</td>
                <td>{{item.flagProcedure}}</td>
                <td>{{item.flagProtesti}}</td>
                <td>{{item.dataEvasione}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here is JSON response

```
{
  "codice_fiscale":"CLLLCA82R69D960T",
  "flagDomande":"N",
  "flagPregiudizievoli":"N",
  "flagProcedure":"N",
  "flagProtesti":"N",
  "dataEvasione":"2021-11-04"

}
```

because the elements in the object are six. it generates `th` for six times with no output. if I print `{{impreses.codice_fiscale}}` then it shows the output. I am not able to understand behavior.

**EDIT**
Second Question

```
{"EventiNegativiPersona":
  {"InfoPersona":
    {"Nominativo":
      {"@attributes":{"cognome":"","nome":""}},
       "CodiceFiscale":"CLLLCA82R69D960T"},
       "ElencoProtesti":{"@attributes": 
       {"flagPresenza":"N"}},"ElencoPregiudizievoli":
       {"@attributes":{"flagPresenza":"N"}}}}
```

I would like to show these but `{{item.EventiNegativiPersona.@parameters.so-on}}` does not work because of `@parameters`. How can i show this?

Comment: the response is an array or an object?

Comment: its json object

Comment: what do you mean by *does not work because of @parameters*?

Comment: as You know when printing with `{{ }}` you cannot just simply write `item.@parameters` its syntax error.

Comment: Try with brackets accessor `{{item.EventiNegativiPersona['@parameters']}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response object shown in your question you could move the `v-for` to the `td` tag :

```
      <table class="..." v-if="showTableAzienda" >
            <thead class="bg-gray-900">
            <tr>
                <th>Codice Fiscale</th>
                <th>Flag Domande</th>
                <th>Flag Pregiudizievoli</th>
                <th>Flag Procedure</th>
                <th>Flag Protesti</th>
                <th>Data Evasione</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-center py-6" >
            <tr>
                <td v-for="item in impreses">{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: may i ask one more question here or i should post new question?

Comment: if it's not too long, you could ask here

Comment: I have edited the question  kindly look at it. Thank you :)